# If PHP statement is ok then answer on next page

Tags: php

I want to display the result on another page. I have this code where the result is on the same page:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ims", $con) or die(mysql_error());
$msg          = "";
$verification = "";
$name         = "";
$parent       = "";
$birth        = "";
$regno        = "";
$issue        = "";
if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
    $query = mysql_query("select * from verification where verification='" . $_POST["verification"] . "'");
    $num   = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($num > 0) {
        $res          = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $verification = $res["verification"];
        $name         = $res["name"];
        $parent       = $res["parent"];
        $birth        = $res["birth"];
        $regno        = $res["regno"];
        $issue        = $res["issue"];
    } else {
        $msg = "Record not found";
    }
}
?>
```

How can change this so that the result displays on another page?

Pls help me. I use this for exam result.

Comment: So you have query.php and you want to display results on other.php?

Comment: FYI - If an exam is testing you on the PHP functions mysql_xxxxx then run away as you are being taught bad things...

Comment: What @IndigoIdentity is trying to say is this... `mysql` is not a language you should be learning. The reason is because `mysql` has been deprecated and will soon stop functioning. It's a waste of your time and money to learn `mysql`. If you're just starting, look for a school/class that will teach you pdo_mysql.

Comment: What @Kuya said, at the very least you should be learning mysqli_ functions but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make use of PHP Sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

In query.php:

```
// Initiate the use of session variables
session_start();
...
do query
...
// Create local storage array
$queryResult = array (
  'verification'=>$res["verification"],
  'name'=>$res["name"],
  'birth'=>$res["birth"],
  'regno'=>$res["regno"],
  'issue'=>$res["issue"]
);
// Transfer local storage to session storage
$_SESSION['queryResult'] = $queryResult;
// Redirect the user
header('Location: http://example.com/result.php');
exit;
```

And then in result.php:

```
// Initiate the use of session variables
session_start();
// Check if the session exists
if (isset($_SESSION['queryResult'])) {
  // Transfer session to local storage
  $queryResult = $_SESSION['queryResult'];
} else {
  printf('Unable to find or access the session information.');
  exit;
}
// Display query result
echo '<pre>';
print_r($queryResult);
echo '</pre>';
```